# Cancel out of integrals

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I have the following type of inequality:
$$
\int_0^{h(x)}\mathrm e^{f(t)} g(t) \mathrm dt>
\int_0^{h(x)}\mathrm e^{f(t)} f(t) \mathrm dt
$$
Question:

Can I cancel the term $\mathrm e^{f(t)}$, as it appears on both sides and the limits of integration are equal?

Thanks a lot

Comment: No, you can't. What makes you think you could do it?

Comment: This question is not off-topic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't. Although, you can claim that
$$
\int_{0}^{h(x)} e^{f(t)}(g(t) - f(t)) dt > 0,
$$
which is indeed not the same as 
$$
\int_{0}^{h(x)} g(t) - f(t) dt > 0.
$$
You can think of $e^{f(t)}$ as a weight-function.

Comment: Thanks, seeing it like this makes it clear....

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Check by yourself with the following counterexample

Let $f(t)=t; g(t)=3.1$ and $h(x)=5$